# Python: How to return only the first true value of this if statement?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, intersection

If I have this following code that takes in points a,b,c,d and says if a/b intersect with c/d, then we add the intersection point to a list (it should be noted that this is all in a nested for loop and points c/d are more like c[i] and d[i+1] being pairs of subsequent points chosen in a larger list of point values). So basically, a/b is constant, but c/d changes each time to test if a/b intersects it.

[This image shows the line a->b (red and green points respectively) and the black points and brown lines represent the lines created by subsequent points. In the left image, the line from a->b will intersect two brown lines, but i only want the code below to return true to the orange circled one (the one closest to the point a) and then append that to sectlist. I also want it to work if there is only one intersection like in the right example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yvYE.jpg)

And here is the code:

```
for i in range(400): #number of total points that together create a polygon
    a = (x[0], y[0])
    b = (0, testpoint1)
    #so a line is made from the first value in x,y and testpoint1
    c = (x[i], y[i])
    d = (x[i+1], y[i+1])
    #and subsequent lines are made for every subsequent value in the original list of values
    if intersect_bool(a,b,c,d) == True:
        sectlist.append(intersect_point(a,b,c,d))
```

This works fine if a/b intersects with only one pair of values c/d, but how can I only have it return True once (and append only the first intersection made and continue with the script)?

Edit: I added a ton to the code so the question is more intelligible + an image with a description

Comment: As a note, I essentially want only the first intersection (assuming there is more than one intersection) that is the closest distance-wise to point b to be added to sectlist

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the question but you might be able to use something like

`if any([intersect_bool(a, b, c, d) for c, d in *insert iterable here*])`

Comment: I would do this, but the it might then return the value of an intersection that is not the first true intersection but rather the first combination of subsequent c/d values in the sectlist. I guess an easier way to explain it is I want the first set of points that intersects and is closest to b.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I Have edited my answer to provide an example.

Given that I am still not clear on how some of the points would look like, I have created a sample example for you, to illustrate one way you can do this, I have used [Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/).

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint, LineString
from shapely.ops import nearest_points

# prepare a sample line and list of points
some_line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (0,3)])
some_points = [Point(1,1), Point(1,2), Point(1,3)]
some_list = list() 

# Get all intersecting points
for p in some_points:
    if p.intersects(some_line):
        some_list.append(p)

# convert gathered points to a list of destinations
destinations = MultiPoint(some_list)
# Find nearest items to a given origin point
nearest_geoms = nearest_points(some_line, destinations) # nearest_points(origin, destinations)
# print the nearest item
print(nearest_geoms[0])
```

I hope this helps in answering your question.

Comment: I would do this, but the it might then return the value of an intersection that is not the first true intersection but rather the first combination of subsequent c/d values in the sectlist. I guess an easier way to explain it is I want the first set of points that intersects and is closest to b.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I still do not have a solid example, so I am illustrating my point as general as possible. The ideas is that you first loop into all points -> for each point find all intersections -> get the closest intersection by some defined logic (I provided using max as an example) -> append only the intersection point that fits that logic into the list -> move to next point. @ChessGrandMaster

Comment: Hey @alt-f4 I added a lot more like you asked. Hopefully the question is clearer. Please let me knkow if you have any more questions as I really need to know how i can code this. thanks!

Comment: @ChessGrandMaster I have updated my answer. I hope this answers what you are looking for.